# Why does GetBasicPropertiesAsync() sometimes throw an Exception?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, dotnetzip

In Windows8, I'm trying to use GetBasicPropertiesAsync() to get the size of a newly created file.  *Sometimes*, but not always (~25% of the time), this call gives an exception of:

```
"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))".
```

The file is created using DotNetZip.  I'm adding thousands of files to the archive which takes a few minutes to run:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFile(...); // for thousands of files
    zip.Save(cr.ArchiveName);
}
var storageFile = await subFolder.GetFileAsync(cr.ArchiveName);  
// storageFile is valid at this point
var basicProperties = await storageFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync(); // BOOM!
```

A few apparently random things seem to decrease the likelihood of the exception:

1. Deleting an existing copy of cr.ArchiveName before the start of the loop.
2. Not viewing the directory using File Explorer

Weird, huh?  It smells like it might be a bug related to [File System Tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133560/replacing-or-recreating-a-file-in-windows-8-rt-keeps-the-old-datecreated-value/14141829#14141829) or maybe it's some internal caching that DotNetZip is performing and holding onto resources (maybe renaming the TEMP file) even after the ZipFile is disposed?

Comment: E_ACCESSDENIED most likely indicates the file being in use, although looking at your code I'm not sure why. Maybe you could try using [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896655) to help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to (unsuccessfully) answer my own question.

At first, I though this was a known issue with DotNetZip holding onto file handles until the next garbage collection.  I am using the SL/WP7 port of DotNetZip from http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/ which presumably doesn't include the bug fixed by this workitem:

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/12727

But, according to that theory, doing:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

should have provided a work around, which it didn't.

Next I tried using **handle**, which didn't show any other activity on the failing StorageFile.

So for now, I'm still stumped.

Comment: To do a real collection, you need to run GC.Collect() again - after WaitForPendingFinalizers, the refs are still not cleared from the heap. So: GC.Collect/GC.Wait/GC.Collect for a real full GC.